# Conversion of Tensorflow-lite model to F16 and INT8

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I need to evaluate performance of CNN (Convolutional Neural Network) on an edge device. I started with understanding what is quantization and how run it in colab using interpreter (emulator). Full code is here -> https://github.com/aravindchakravarti/OptimizeNetworks/blob/main/Quantization_Aware_Training.ipynb

I was trying to convert CNN to Float-16 (F16) and Int-8 (T8) quantization levels and wanted to see what is the difference in

- Inference time
- Model size

I did F16 model conversion by using

```
converter_fl16 = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(q_aware_model)
converter_fl16.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter_fl16.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
quantized_tflite_model_f16 = converter_fl16.convert()
```

And converted to T8

```
converter_t8 = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(q_aware_model)
converter_t8.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

quantized_tflite_model_t8 = converter_t8.convert()

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=quantized_tflite_model_t8)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

When I evaluated with respect to Inference Time, 
F32 (Without Quantization) = 1.3s 
F16 (With Quantization) = 0.6s 
T8 (With Quantization) = 0.59s

When I evaluated with respect to Model Size, 
F32 (Without Quantization) = 83KB 
F16 (With Quantization) = 25KB 
T8 (With Quantization) = 25KB

My question is,
Why I am getting same model size and inference time for both F16 and T8? Am I not quantizing properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the int8 model to fp16 and the converter just keeps everything as int8. That's why both of the models are the same.
The issue is in the convert line, should be

```
converter_fl16 = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
```

After updating you should see 
FP32 83k
FP16 44k
I8 25k

You can also inspect the generated model using for example netron or tflite visualize tool to verify.

Comment: Hi @Karim, Thanks, Actually, I am doing quantization aware training. That is why I used "q_aware_model" for model conversion. If you see my github code, q_aware_model is generated using "tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_mode" which will not convert the model to 8 bit.

Comment: I think you misunderstand FP16 quant in TFLite.
FP16 in TFLite is just weight only, just to decrease the file size, even in CPU runtime it will use FP32 by dequantizing FP16 to FP32 and trigger FP32 kernels.
GPU delegate is the one that doesn't trigger FP32 and will remove the dequantize and run things in FP16.